# No Windows after installing Kali

Tags: windows, boot, grub, kali-linux

Yesterday I installed Kali, however, after the install had finished there were no bootable operating systems. Neither my Windows 10 or Kali would launch. After reading around I found repair boot, made a live CD, and "fixed" the grub. This allowed me to launch my Kali OS but it still would not let me launch my Windows 10. Here is the [PasteBin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23415946/)

This brings me to a few hours ago. Since then I have not been able to fix my system so it launches Win10. I can mount my hard drive that had my Win10 OS on and that was not touched during Kali setup, I have tried the methods [here (except manually writing an entry)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows).

I have also tried booting on the HDD that has the partition for Win10 but that provides me with a black screen and a flashing white line. The same result that I had before I ran boot repair and got Kali to work. I read it my be related to secure boot but that is disabled.

So I am asking how can I boot into windows, either by booting onto the hard drive that contains it or adding it to the Grub Kali launches off?

Comment: Make sure you also try to fix MBR

Comment: @Tealkine Using what? The Windows boot disc?

Comment: "after reading around I found repair boot, made a live CD, and "fixed" the grub. "

Using repair boot. Also repair-boot did its job, it fixed grub.